# xPage application - using document.removeFromFolder and document.putInFolder throws error

Tags: xpages

I have a xPage application which shows list of emails of the currently logged user. Using some button user can remove selected email from inbox and put it into another folder.

UI works fine except the fact that document.removeFromFolder and document.putInFolder in my JAVA backend class throws an error "Notes error: You are not authorized to perform that operation ($Inbox)" . There is the same error for removing or putting document from/into inbox/another folder. But ACL is correct, user can create emails, delete them ...

Has anyone some hint whats wrong here?

Here is the error message I'm getting(just a small part):

> JavaScriptMethodBinding.invoke(JavaScriptMethodBinding.java:111)
> 	...
>   32 more
> Caused by: NotesException: Notes error: You are not
>   authorized to perform t hat operation
>   (($Inbox))
> 	at
>   lotus.domino.local.Document.removeFromFolder(Unknown Source)

Comment: Maybe you should put some code here. The signer of your code has access to the mailbox? Is it a java agent?

Comment: Hmm, I just found this. Mailbox is on server1 and application runs on two different servers(server2 and server3). (I have two application servers). This error occures only on one of these two, on first server it fails with this error, on second server its working fine. So generaly the code is fine, as told previously user can create emails, remove emails using my app(so permissions are ok), just can't put/remove email from folder. It must be some configuration issue, will get back when find details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of checkpoints to watch out for:

- If you use "session as signer that signer needs to have access to the mail file
- If application and NSF are on different servers you need a setting in the server document needs to include a trust relation for these servers. That's the server document - Security - left column, bottom: Trusted servers.
- I presume the servers have ACL access

Hope that helps